# 2-dimensional bins from a pandas DataFrame based on 3 columns

Tags: python, pandas, binning

I'm trying to create 2-dimensional bins from a pandas DataFrame based on 3 columns. Here a snippet from my DataFrame:

```
      Scatters  N   z           Dist_first
---------------------------------------
0     0         0   0.096144    2.761508
1     1         0   -8.229910   17.403039
2     2         0   0.038125    21.466233
3     3         0   -2.050480   29.239867
4     4         0   -1.620470   NaN
5     5         0   -1.975930   NaN
6     6         0   -11.672200  NaN
7     7         0   -16.629000  26.554049
8     8         0   0.096002    NaN
9     9         0   0.176049    NaN
10    10        0   0.176005    NaN
11    11        0   0.215408    NaN
12    12        0   0.255889    NaN
13    13        0   0.301834    27.700308
14    14        0   -29.593600  9.155065
15    15        1   -2.582290   NaN
16    16        1   0.016441    2.220946
17    17        1   -17.329100  NaN
18    18        1   -5.442320   34.520919
19    19        1   0.001741    39.579189
```

For my result each Dist_first should be binned with all "z <= 0" of lower index within a group "N" than the Distance itself. "Scatters" is a copy of the index left from an operation in an earlier stage of my code which is not relevant here. Nonetheless I came to use it instead of the index in the example below. The bins for the distances and z's are in 10 m and 0.1 m steps, respectively and I can obtain a result from looping through groups of the dataFrame:

```
# create new column for maximal possible distances per group N
for j in range(N.groupby('N')['Dist_first'].count().max()):
    N[j+1] = N.loc[N[N['Dist_first'].notna()].groupby('N')['Scatters'].nlargest(j+1).groupby('N').min()]['Dist_first']
    # fill nans with zeros to allow 
    N[j+1] = N[j+1].fillna(0)
    # make sure no value is repeated
    if j+1 > 1:
        N[j+1] = N[j+1]-N[list(np.arange(j)+1)].sum(axis=1)

# and set all values <= 0 to NaN
N[N[list(np.arange(N.groupby('N')['Dist_first'].count().max())+1)] <= 0] = np.nan

# backwards fill to make sure every distance gets all necessary depths
N[list(np.arange(N.groupby('N')['Dist_first'].count().max())+1)] = N.set_index('N').groupby('N').bfill().set_index('Scatters')[list(np.arange(N.groupby('N')['Dist_first'].count().max())+1)]
            
# bin the result(s)
for j in range(N.groupby('N')['Dist_first'].count().max()):
    binned = N[N['z'] >= 0].groupby([pd.cut(N[N['z'] >= 0]['z'], bins_v, include_lowest=True), pd.cut(N[N['z'] >= 0][j+1], bins_h, include_lowest=True)])
    binned = binned.size().unstack()
    ## rename
    binned.index = N_v.index; binned.columns = N_h.index
    ## and sum up with earlier chunks
    V = V+binned
```

This bit of code works just fine and the result for the small snippet of the data I've shared looks like this:

```
Distance [m]    0.0     10.0    20.0    30.0    40.0
Depth [m]                   
----------------------------------------------------
0.0     1   1   1   4   2
0.1     1   2   2   4   0
0.2     0   3   0   3   0
0.3     0   2   0   2   0
0.4     0   0   0   0   0
```

However, the whole dataset(s) are excesively large (> 300 mio rows each) and looping through all rows is not an option. Therefore I'm looking for some vectorized solution.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to calculate creiteria in extra columns and then use Pandas standard binning function, like qcut. It can be applied separately along the 2 binning dimensions. Not most elegant, but definitely vectorized.